# Issue creating a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, mezzanine

So I'm following this tutorial http://rosslaird.com/blog/building-a-project-with-mezzanine/ for building a project with Mezzanine. I am extremely new to all of this stuff (including Linux and the command line) and frankly do not really know what I am doing. I am at this part of the tutorial:

> Run this command within the same directory as your local_settings.py and settings.py files: python manage.py createdb

The tutorial says that after I enter the "python manage" command I will be "asked to create a super-user, to provide details that user, and to answer a few more questions". When I entered the command none of those questions showed up. Why is this? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to run this on the commandline right (terminal)?

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER 
sudo -u postgres psql 
postgres=# \password [enter your username] 
Enter new password: 
Enter it again: 
\q 
createdb $USER;
```

Change $USER with your designated name.

Comment: Yes I am trying to run this in the terminal. The tutorial says that after I enter the command I posted, I should get a few line entries like this:

"Creating tables ... 
Creating table auth_permission 
Creating table auth_group 
... 
Creating table django_comment_flags"

Instead I get lines like this:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/daniel/myfirstenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()"

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that the link you provided is 404'd (Most likely because this post is over 2 years old) .

But... I think I found it [here](http://laird223.rssing.com/chan-57964223/latest.php) (sort of)... There's a few bits and pieces missing which might have made it confusing. The "manage.py" should be in the parent directory that's prior to where your "settings.py | local_settings.py | urls.py" files reside. Just make sure you are in the appropriate directory when running the manage command. An easy `ls` or `ls -la` command will show you where your files are at within the directory. I myself am a novice Mezzanine user. I've been playing around with it for a year now and hope this info can serve as a quickstart guide for setting up Mezzanine on PostgreSQL while also resolving your issue.

So... Once the following conditions are met you should be able to create a Mezzanine project with a PostgreSQL database instance. But first, make sure you have Mezzanine set up and running without warnings or errors.

**For Mezzanine Setup...**

Preconditions:
You've installed Python, pip, etc...

1. Get virtualenv & virtualenvwrapper installed and configured.
   `pip install virtualenv`
   `pip install virtualenvwrapper`
2. Make sure to add your environment variables for your virtual environments. Just point the paths to where you want your Mezzanine projects to live as well as the environments. An easy way to do it is edit your bashrc in the home directory. I like to keep my virtualenvs separate from my working directory but adjust the paths to how you like. Just `sudo vi ~/.bashrc` then add the following...

`## Virtualenvwrapper Settings
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/envs/mezzanine/projects/live/here
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Note: Do `i` to insert text and when done editing type `ctrl + c` to exit the prompt then `:wq!` to write (save) and quit. Then close your terminal and open a new one so the new changes take effect. If not, restart your computer.

3. Next, cd over to your project directory `cd ~/envs/mezzanine/projects/live/here` and create your virtualenv for your Mezzanine project (It'll activate once created).
   `mkvirtualenv environment_name`

You can deactivate your environment by simply typing `deactivate` in terminal. To re-activate your environment, type `workon environment_name`

4. Now you can install Mezzanine...
   `pip install -U mezzanine`
5. Then create your Mezzanine project and watch those folders get created in your project directory...
   `mezzanine-project project_name`
6. Collect your templates & static files.
   `python manage.py collecttemplates`
   `python manage.py collectstatic`
7. Now create your db instance (by default this will be SQLite if you haven't changed anything in settings.py .
8. Make sure you have your ALLOWED_HOSTS configured and edit your settings.py if you haven't already. 
   `vi ~/envs/mezzanine/projects/live/here/project_name/project_name/settings.py` .

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1:8000',
    'localhost',
    'www.mydomain.com' #if you want to set that too.
]`

Note:  Don't forget to save your changes `ctrl+c` & `:wq!` .

9. At this point you should be able to go back a directory and run your server `python manage.py runserver` and get a response from your localhost (loopback address) at port 8000 by opening a browser and typing in 127.0.0.1:8000. (make sure your environment has been activated first)

**Now For Your PostgreSQL Database...**

Check this out. It's a pretty good resource and even touches base on virtualenv. You can also replace the Django references with Mezzanine (almost). The most important part is the database setup portion...

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

1. Install Postgres and dependencies. (You might need to run as `sudo` with `-H` flag here)
   `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib`
2. Install psysopg2 (Might need `sudo -H` as well)
   `sudo pip install psycopg2`
3. Login as "postgres" user:
   `sudo -su postgres`
4. Run the psql shell command: `psql`. You should see the 'postgres=#' text.
5. Now, create your database (Remember to end psql statements with a semicolon;) `CREATE DATABASE mydb;`
6. Create database user: `CREATE USER mydbuser WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword';`
7. Set your user roles:
   `ALTER ROLE mydbuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
   ALTER ROLE mydbuser SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
   ALTER ROLE mydbuser SET timezone TO 'UTC';`

8: Then give the database user access rights: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO mydbuser;`

9. Type `ctrl + d` to exit shell, then type `exit` to exit postgres user.
10. Now, go to your settings.py and local_settings.py in your Mezzanine project's working directory and modify your DATABASES settings with the credentials you previously created... `cd ~/envs/mezzanine/projects/live/here/project_name/project_name/` and then `vi settings.py`

`DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'mydb',
            'USER': 'mydbuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }`

Note: Don't forget local_settings.py

9. Now you can create your database via manage.py.
   `python manage.py createdb`
10. The above command should prompt you to do the initial setup of your database along with your site info, as well as create a superuser. Just follow the prompts. To create additional superusers just do
    `python manage.py createsuperuser' .
11. Now go back a directory to the project root `cd ..` and run your server `python manage.py runserver` . And now... you should have your new Mezzanine project running on PostgreSQL. Congratulations!! :)

Answer (score -1):

The tutorial is just wrong. The writer has got confused with the Postgres `createdb` command used earlier, and the actual manage.py command, which is `syncdb`.

You would be better off using the actual Django tutorial.

Comment: When I used "python manage.py syncdb" I was given the same problem as when I used createdb. Any help? 

Also I would you be able to link to the specific part of the Django tutorial that would help me for where I am? I would greatly appreciate that. Thank you.